# Why `Concurrently` is not a monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, promise, monads

I'm reading the doc of package [async](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.20/async-2.2.1/Control-Concurrent-Async.html), and trying to find something similar to JavaScript's Promise, and I find `Concurrently`, which is the most close concept that implemented `Functor`, `Applicative` (Promise.all), `Alternative` (Promise.race). But it doesn't implement `Monad` (Promise.then), I'm wondering why.

I think it maybe because `(>>=)` is a sequential operation, which conflict with the name `Concurrently`, but is this the only reason? is there some more important reason here?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the reason: the whole point of monads is that they encode _order of operations_, and `Concurrently` expresses parallelism, which is an inherently unordered thing. But `Concurrently` is not actually equivalent to JS promise. Promises don't give you parallelism, only asynchrony. Perhaps if you described what your ultimate goal is, people here could help you find the right solution.

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/simonmar/async/pull/26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The `Monad` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad) states that `(<*>)` and `ap` should be equivalent. `(<*>)` for `Concurrently` evaluates both the LHS and the RHS at the same time. `ap` can't evaluate the RHS until the LHS is done, since `(>>=)` needs to finish evaluating the LHS before it can call the function that gives it the RHS.

Comment: But why can't we just let `ap = (<*>)`, is there any constraints that ap must be implemented by `(>>=)` ?

Comment: I have read the code just now, and find that maybe it is just a Historical issues?

Comment: `ap` isn't in the `Monad` class. It's defined as `ap m1 m2 = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (x1 x2) }`, for every Monad. And no, it's not a historical issue.

Comment: So I'm wondering, why can't we design a monad, which Applicative is a concurrent version, and Monad is a sequential version?  why `(<*>)` and `ap` must be equivalent? what is the motivation to add this rule?

Comment: For your first 2 questions, because the Monad laws say so. For your third, lots of reasons. See https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3v9qlf/why_must_ap/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/46913472/7509065 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/24112786/7509065 for some of them.

Comment: I think i got it. these laws like `pure = return` and `(<*>) = ap` makes a promise that the `Applicative` and `Monad` instance of some specific data have the same semantics.

Comment: @luochen1990: exactly there are contracts between `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad`. One can not just implement these in an isolated manner, the `Functor` "partly determines" the "shape" of the `Monad`, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, I think maybe Haxl is what I want.